# using mscomm32.ocx in crystalreports application

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'm using vs 2010 with sap crystal reports for vs 2010. when I'm using Microsoft communication control (MSCOMM32) to communicate with my USB Modem in crystal repororts application and running the application, I'm getting this error.
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MSCommLib, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
while when I romove MSCOMM32 control from my crystal report application it works/runs fine.
I'm not getting any error using MSCOMM32 Control if I don't use crystal report with my C#.Net application.
Can anyone plz solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why to use such an old control like Mscomm32 for sending sms. try using Serial port instead. hear is the code example for using serial port instead of MSCOMM32

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var sp = new SerialPort("COM4"))
        {
            sp.Open();
            sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + "phone no" + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.WriteLine("your text message" + (char)26);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could help, but I had exactly the same error using Visual Studio 2013 with the library interop.MSCommlib.dll. The error appeared on running time, not compilation time.
On compiling I could notice this warning:

vbc : warning BC40059: A reference was created to embedded interop assembly 'Interop.MSCommLib' because of an indirect reference to that assembly from assembly 'AxInterop.MSCommLib'. Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly.

I solved the error editing the .vbproj file in the part where the library interop.MSCommlib is included (Reference Include="Interop.MSCommLib") and changed the parameter "EmbedInteropTypes" from "true" to "false".

The problem happens because on being that parameter set as "true" the library was not being copied in to the "bin" folder during the compilation. As far as I understand this happens because the compiler interprets there is some components embedded into another related library which was already copied.

I hope this could help.